# Got a Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSMTP() on null

Tags: php, phpmailer

Excuse this stupid question.. But i created an instance of phpMailer but i still get this error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSMTP() on null

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
require('vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require('vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php');
require('vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;


class Mail {
  private $mail;

  private $MAIL_HOST = "<host>";
  private $MAIL_PORT = "<port>";
  private $MAIL_USER = "<user>";
  private $MAIL_PASSWORD = "<censored>";

  private function initialize() {
    $this->mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->isSMTP(true);
    $mail->Host = $MAIL_HOST;
    $mail->PORT = $MAIL_PORT;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $MAIL_USER;
    $mail->Password = $MAIL_PASSWORD;
  }

  public function sendHTMLMail($fromEmail, $fromName, $replyTo, $recipientEmail, $subject, $body, $altBody) {
    $this->initialize();

    // Define sender and recipient
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addReplyTo($replyTo);
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = $altBody;

    if($mail->send()) {
     echo 'Message has been sent';
      } else {
     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
  }

}
?>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You're not correctly referencing your `Mail` class's `PHPMailer` instance.
Change all instances of `$mail->` to `$this->mail->`

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
require('vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
require('vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php');
require('vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;


class Mail {
  private $mail;

  private $MAIL_HOST = "<host>";
  private $MAIL_PORT = "<port>";
  private $MAIL_USER = "<user>";
  private $MAIL_PASSWORD = "<censored>";

  private function initialize() {
    $this->mail = new PHPMailer();

    $this->mail->isSMTP(true);
    $this->mail->Host = $MAIL_HOST;
    $this->mail->PORT = $MAIL_PORT;
    $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $this->mail->Username = $MAIL_USER;
    $this->mail->Password = $MAIL_PASSWORD;
  }

  public function sendHTMLMail($fromEmail, $fromName, $replyTo, $recipientEmail, $subject, $body, $altBody) {
    $this->initialize();

    // Define sender and recipient
    $this->mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $this->mail->addReplyTo($replyTo);
    $this->mail->addAddress($recipient);

    // Content
    $this->mail->isHTML(true);
    $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
    $this->mail->Body = $body;
    $this->mail->AltBody = $altBody;

    if($this->mail->send()) {
     echo 'Message has been sent';
      } else {
     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $this->mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Gosh, i'm really braindead.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, since you’re using composer, *use composer* to load PHPMailer as well. It’s what it’s for.